# Alternate words for tiny houses

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Tiny houses (70 to 400 sq.ft. according to the [American Tiny House Association](http://americantinyhouseassociation.org/)) are becoming a trend in the US.

Can you please help me come up with alternative words for tiny houses? I can't use small in place of tiny as it is a different category of house i.e. 400 to 1000 sq. ft.

I have read petite but it is used for women. Minuscule also does not seem right as it seems too tiny for a house.

Thank you in advance.

Context: I am writing a 500-word blog about tiny houses.

Comment: *Tiny houses* is a collocation with a defined meaning, so it makes no sense to ask for an alternative noun phrase. If you tried to use different wording, people won't understand you. Are you, instead, asking for a suitable *adjective to describe their smallness?* If so, (a) have you consulted a thesaurus? What other synonyms for tiny have you considered and rejected? And (b) please [edit] your question to include a sample sentence showing how your word would be used, as required for all [tag:single-word-requests] questions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bijou](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bijou) is sometimes used for spaces and furniture which are small but attractive.

Merriam Webster defines it as

> something delicate, elegant, or highly prized

It is actually French and means "jewel" but has been adopted into English with the above meaning.

Comment: Excellent. This works as well. It is defined in Cambridge Dictionary as (especially of a building) small but attractive. Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: For something less fussy, try *gem*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The advantage of "bijou" is that it can be used directly as an adjective (for example "a bijou cottage") in a way that "gem" cannot.  You can use "gem" to refer to a property but only using "of a" as well (for example "a gem of a cottage"). Also "gem" doesn't quite carry the association of small size.

Comment: I had received a positive review of the blog plost. Again, thank you guys for the help. I used mini and bijou residence as alternative terms. I cannot use tiny house repeatedly since Google regards it as keyword stuffing.

Answer (score 1):

You could say ***mini-houses***. As a prefix, *mini-* can precede nouns to mean:

> smaller or less important than a normal example of the same thing:
>
> - He has his own ***mini-**refrigerator* in his room. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mini))

In fact, [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mini-houses&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmini%20-%20houses%3B%2Cc0) shows that the us of *mini-houses* increases, which may be related to the fact that such houses have become trendy lately.

*[Mini houses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mini%20houses%22&sxsrf=ALeKk003HG0LcHo_m0zvXFmdRmU2F-wKnA%3A1627110494272&ei=Xrz7YNeYENLWgQbYhpPYAg&oq=%22mini%20houses%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIICAAQBxAKEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFDgaVj0b2DWkwFoAXACeACAAYICiAG7A5IBBTEuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjXv5X4kvvxAhVSa8AKHVjDBCsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5)*, without the hyphen, is also correct.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This works. I will use it in the blog post. I just need one more alternative word to sprinkle in my blog - actually a realtor's blog who is my client.